# Can I write a custom-rendered control of sliverlight which is rendered by xna in Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna, custom-controls

With the Windows Phone 7.1 SDK, we can build sl-xna mix Apps.
It provides us these abilities:

1. render the XNA content in a silverlight page
2. sliverlight controls can also be rendered in the same page.

Here is what I need:

I want to use a sliverlight control to manage my XNA content, so that I can take the advantages of silverlight utilities and save me a lot of works.

For example: I can add a scrollviewer to the MainGamePage.xaml then add my XNA Sprites to the scrollviewer, so the silverlight framework will do the scrolling and scroll bar stuff for me.

Is it possible now? If it is so, I won't need to fulfill my own scrollview in the XNA and etc.

Is there someone has the same idea and can help me please.

Any kind of tips or any other solutions will be appreciated.

Thank you guys again!

Answer (score 0):

But that is exactly what the "Windows Phone Silverlight and XNA Application" project template does, right? It has a page that is rendered using XNA, while a page is just a control. I am not sure if you could have multiple XNA-rendered controls on screen at the same time or how performant it would be to have them, but that should work.

Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: Thanks xyzzer. Kind of a busy these days. I khow waht you mean. But the point is, the page is using a timer to do the XNA update and draw. It only provides the global shared device for XNA to render in the whole screen but not a draw method for the page itself, and also the page is only a container for the sl-controls which I don't khow how to render manually. I hope I can do this:add a scrollviewer to the page then add a customised sl-control which is rendered by XNA to the view,so the XNA rendered sl-control can scroll automaticly. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not even sure that having more than one XNA control is possible, but I can assure you it is not desirable. The XNA control used by Silverlight is a complete game in itself, with its content manager and all the bells and whistles, so having several running at the same time is overkill.

Simply use Silverlight content on your Silverlight scroll view. Since you can communicate with XNA, you can know which images to show without issues and update them as the game requires.

Comment: Thanks Elideb.My XNA control is actually a silverlight control indeed.I just want to change their default silverlight draw method such as a sliverlight Button with 3D ball lookface.